# How to apply condition on column while iterating over every row of dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

[Link of the data sets of csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ODUvDhiJn3Qdjy58TwSW9Aey8xIhDEZ9/view?usp=sharing)

Link contains the `.csv` file in which one column is state name and number of tooth lost. I want to calculate average teeth lost of children in every state. I tried to use `df.interrows` but I cannot use condition for columns value of any particular row.

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    if row["State"] == "NSW":
        Count += row["Number of teeth lost"]
```

If NSW state contain 3 values 2,3,4, then I need to calculate average of this three number and same for other six state. I am using pandas for manipulating csv file.

Comment: Use `df.groupby("State")["Total number of teeth lost"].mean()` if you need to get all states.

Comment: Avoid adding image for the dataset. Add an actual data sample so that its easier to replicate

Comment: @nucsit26 link is actual csv file not an image Thank you henry it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try using `df.loc[df['State'] == "NSW"]['Number of tooth lost'].mean()`

It selects all the rows where the condition inside the `.loc` bracket is true and then just selects the column 'Number of tooth lost' to compute the mean for.

This is much faster than iterating all the rows as you did because pandas handles the operations on a lower level.